# Python: list of strings

Tags: python

I am trying to look at a .txt file and make a list of words in it. I want the words to be strings, but the ouput makes them lists.

```
import csv, math, os
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\jmela\canopy')
f=open("romeo.txt")

words = []

    for row in csv.reader(f):
        line = str(row)
        for word in line.split():
            if word not in words: 
                print word
                words.append(word)

    words.sort()
    print words
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why in the earth you convert your rows to string then split that?

Comment: This doesn't directly address your problem, but if you want a collection that has no duplicate values, consider using a set.

Comment: You are getting a list of strings, you probably are confusing it because some of them have `[` in them. See @Kasra comment for why

Comment: how does your text file looks like? csv reader try to read rows and split columns based on delimiter. if your file is a list of words separated with comma, "row" will already be a list of words as strings.

Comment: When I try to do it directly:


for row in csv.reader(f):
    for word in row.split():
        if word not in words: 
            print word
            words.append(word)
            
I get this error: 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: This is the text file: http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt

Comment: `words` is a list of strings. Each element of `words` is a string. Maybe what you want is to print each string from `words` without the brackets and commas (which will be present if you print the list the way you did on your code). If that's the case, you should loop through `words`. `for word in words: print word`

Answer (score 1):

based on your latest comment, doesn't look like you really need to use csv reader. just try this:

```
words = []
for line in open("romeo.txt", "r"):
    for word in line.split():
        if word not in words: 
            words.append(word)

words.sort()
print words
```

and like Kevin suggested, use set() instead of list.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. 

I don't follow what was wrong with my original code. Do you know why that didn't work?

Comment: yes like I said csv reader split every row into columns based on given delimiter (default to comma). so row was actually something like ["this is a sentence"] (list with one string which is the whole line, since there were no commas), and then you turned it into string (eg '["this is a sentence"]'), and then you tried to split it based on spaces... please read about csv reader some more, and next time you should debug and see what you get in every iteration of the loop, it will save you some time.. :)

Comment: I understand this & have learned from your explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `set` to hold your words. This would give you a unique word list. Any non-alpha characters and converted to spaces. The line is split into words and lowercased to make sure they match.

```
word_set = set()
re_nonalpha = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z ]+')

with open(r"romeo.txt", "r") as f_input:
    for line in f_input:
        line = re_nonalpha.sub(' ', line)  # Convert all non a-z to spaces

        for word in line.split():
            word_set.add(word.lower())

word_list = list(word_set)
word_list.sort()
print word_list
```

This would give you a list holding the following words:

```
['already', 'and', 'arise', 'breaks', 'but', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'it', 'juliet', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'who', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']
```

Updated to also remove any punctuation.

Comment: Make sure to account for an extra space or hyphens

Answer (score 0):

Don't read the text file as csv then. Simply remove all punctuation and non-letter/non-space characters like this:

```
def replacePunct(string):
    alphabets = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    for s in string:
        if s not in alphabets:
            string = string.replace(s, " ")
            replacePunct(string)
    string = string.split()
    string = [x for x in string if x != " "]
    return {set(string): len(string)}
```

Comment: Read the file as a normal text file and run this program for each line